# Show that $[M]_t=t$ for every $t\ge 0$ is equivalent to $M_t^2-t$ is a continuous local martingale.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

A continuous local martingale $M$ is a Brownian motion if and only if $[M]_t=t$ for every $t\ge 0$. Or equivalently if and only if $M_t^2-t$ is a continuous local martingale.

How do we prove these two conditions are equivalent? This is to show that $[M]_t=t$ for every $t\ge 0$ is equivalent to $M_t^2-t$ is a continuous local martingale.

---

My work: if $[M]_t=t$, we know that $M_t^2-[M]_t=M_t^2-t$ is a continuous local martingale. But how do show that the converse statement?

Comment: What is the notation $[M]_t$?

Comment: Hint : Levy's characterization of Brownian motion (Karatzas&Shreve *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*).

Comment: Isn't the definition of the quadratic variation, $\left[M\right]_t$, that it is the unique increasing process such that $M^2_t - \left[M\right]_t$ is a local martingale?

Comment: @SacAndSac $[M]_t$ is the quadratic variation of $M$.

Comment: @KurtG. Yes, I know this is Levy's characterization of Brownian motion. I want to know why these two conditions are equivalent..

Comment: If you want the full story. You need Levy's characterisation of BM plus this: The [quadratic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation) is defined as
$$
[M]_t=\lim_{\|P\|\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^n(M_{t_k}-M_{t_{k-1}})^2
$$
and is for continuous local martingales equal to the unique adapted increasing process $\langle M\rangle_t$ such that
$$
M^2_t-\langle M\rangle_t
$$
is a martingale (see [1] Thm. 1.4.10: existence and uniqueness of the Doob-Meyer decomposition). [1] Karatzas&Shreve *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*